# How do I stream videos from Google Drive using Node.js

Tags: node.js, server, google-drive-api, video-streaming

Is there any way to implement streaming videos stored in Google Drive using Node.js?

Like streaming videos on a website via my custom node server that fetcher chunks of video from Google Drive and sends to the website for example?

**Goal** - Stream videos stored in Google Drive on a website

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here.

## 1. [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk)

You can use the Google Drive API to get the webContentLink of a video, then use that to stream it on the client.

```
// UNTESTED
let fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
let link = drive.files.get({
  fileId: fileId,
  alt: 'media',
  fields: 'webContentLink'
})
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Done');
      console.log(link); // send to client as needed
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
```

Alternatively, if you want to download it server-side, check [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#node.js).

## 2. Share directly from Google Drive

http://sangsoonam.github.io/2019/07/27/how-to-embed-a-google-drive-video.html